# Specifying Segue for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a collection of items I'm putting into a menu for the time being while I work out my layout planning but I am having trouble with figuring out how to work the DidSelectRow with the indexPath.row -

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class DispatchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var videos: [DispatchMenuItem] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        videos = createArray()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 65.0
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }


    func createArray() -> [DispatchMenuItem] {

        let video1 = DispatchMenuItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "truckUnloadIcon"), title: "Open Manifests")
        let video2 = DispatchMenuItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "podIcon"), title: "Customer Pickup")
        return [video1, video2]
    }
}


extension DispatchViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let video = videos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DispatchMenuItemCell") as! DispatchMenuItemCell
        cell.setVideo(video: video)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
        print(indexPath)
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToOpenManifests", sender: nil)
        }else if indexPath.row == 2{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCustomerPickupForm", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

You can see near the bottom my `DidSelectRow`, but it doesn't want to print out the indexPath.row so I am assuming that the row being selected is somehow now being passed along through the extension.

Are there any suggestions? I've usually done this through just a UITableViewController and have never had this issue, but somewhere here I seem to be getting stuck.

Comment: You never set the table view's `delegate` property.

Comment: Also, the first row is 0, not 1

Answer (score 0):

It will not print out the indexPath as you have not set the delegate. Implementing just the method is not sufficient, `tableView` needs to know who is going to implement the delegate methods.

There is a difference between delegate and datasource.

`tableView.dataSource` will help you to fetch numberofSections, numberofRowsInASection, TableCell Object

`tableView.delegate` will help you to manage the selection and deselection.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        videos = createArray()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 65.0
        tableView.dataSource = self
//Add this
         tableView.delegate = self
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below the first line of code in viewDid load method and improve your code like below.

```
tableView.delegate = self

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
        print(indexPath)
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToOpenManifests", sender: nil)
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCustomerPickupForm", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```